# Making a hyperlink clickable cell of a DataFrame in Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, pandas-styles

I'm trying to display the dataframe df (in the code below) in a [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) app.

In Jupyter Notebook, the code run successfully and without any problems.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['stackoverflow', 'gis stackexchange', 'meta stackexchange'],
    'url': ['https://stackoverflow.com', 'https://gis.stackexchange.com/', 'https://meta.stackexchange.com']
})

def make_clickable(url, name):
    return '<a href="{}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">{}</a>'.format(url, name)


df['link'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_clickable(x['url'], x['name']), axis=1)
df.style
```

#### Result in Jupyter Notebook

[image]

But when I try to implement it in a Streamlit app (by replacing the two last lines by the one below) I get an error.

```
st.dataframe(df.style.apply(
    lambda x: make_clickable(x['url'], x['name']), axis=1))
```

#### Result/Error with Streamlit

> ValueError: Function <function  at 0x0000028F008DC9D0>
> resulted in the apply method collapsing to a Series. Usually, this is
> the result of the function returning a single value, instead of
> list-like.

Do you have any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render HTML in Streamlit, you can use [st.markdown](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text/st.markdown), e.g.:

```
return st.markdown('<a href="{}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">{}</a>'.format(url, name),unsafe_allow_html=True)
```