# Making a clickable Hyperlink to Download Local .pdf file in Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I have been trying to display a dataframe where a column consists a link to download a .pdf file from the local file system in streamlit. I have the link showing up perfectly fine in streamlit app but when I click on the link nothing seems to happen. I have followed this question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325543/making-a-hyperlink-clickable-cell-of-a-dataframe-in-streamlit/73407464#73407464), which was asked previously but looks like I am making a mistake somewhere. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

This is my code below:

```
import os as o
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


df = pd.DataFrame({
     'name': ['John', 'Mathew', 'Sato']
     'link': ['C://Users//Satokuzuma//Documents//sample1.pdf',  'C://Users//Satokuzuma//Documents//sample2.pdf', 'C://Users//Satokuzuma//Documents//sample3.pdf']
})

def make_clickable(url, name):
    return '<a href="{}" download="{}.pdf">DN</a>'.format(url, name)

def fun(path):
    
    f_url = o.path.basename(path)
   
    return '<a target="_blank" href="{}" download>{}</a>'.format(path, f_url)

df = df.style.format({'link' : fun})

st.write(df.to_html(render_links=True,escape=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

With Results in Streamlit app as Below:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcwxc.png)

When the link is clicked nothing happens no error or pop-up. My aim here is for the file to get downloaded when the clicked on the link. Any help or direction on this is greatly appreciated.

Tried to make a clickable hyperlink to download a .pdf located in a local system folder. Everything seems to work but when clicked on the hyperlink nothing happens.

Comment: This works OK for me after I add a comma after `'Sato']`.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen my bad that was a typo from my end. It's not working when I click on the hyperlink.